# How can I have an application stack multiple processes into the same application domain?

Tags: .net, applicationdomain

So here's an example of what I'm wanting to do:

Run test.exe, new Windows process is created, new CLR Application Domain is created, new CLR process is created.
Run test.exe, new Windows process is created, realizes CLR Application Domain exists, restarts CLR process in the first CLR Application Domain and closes with Windows process.
20 more instances of test.exe are run and they all exist in the same windows process and the same CLR Application Domain.

This is, at least, the idea.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A CLR appdomain can never contain multiple Windows processes, it's always the other way around. I don't think a "CLR process" is a well defined term, but I think you can accomplish what you want by creating a ["single instance" application](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=C%23+single+instance+application).

Comment: this seems about right, my concern is i want a logical seperation between the processes in the application domain, as i understand it it's something like this:

Windows process->AppDomain->ClrProcess.

is this about right?